# android: handling touch event for overlapping views

Tags: android, boolean, ontouchlistener

I have a overlapping view that covers the whole screen. I wanna call some events when user makes some gesture over that overlapping view like swiping,  moving his finger... whatever.. while the overlapping view will handle the touch event. But I want the other views behind/underneath that overlapping view to handle the touch event if user just single tap( doesn't swipe, move ) ..

All I want is if there is a movement, overlapping view will handle the touch event, if not then other views underneath that overlapping view will handle the touch event..

how can I do this?

NOTE: I'm trying to make something like drawerlayout. remember?  we can click those components in a drawerlayout. But beside that,  swiping over those components also collapses/moves drawerlayout.  And I noticed drawerlayout has android property clickable="false" but it still can handle touch event (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) but when I try it on other layout and return false, it only handle MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

Comment: Try adding a Gesture listener in onTouch of overlapping view and for underneath view add onClick listener.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the purpose of you, but you can try to use the attribute follow

android:duplicateParentState="true"

Comment: I'm trying to make something like drawerlayout. remember?  we can clip those components in a drawerlayout. But beside that,  swiping over those components also collapses/moves drawerlayout.  And I noticed drawerlayout has android property clickable="false" but it still can handle touch event (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) but when I try it on other layout and return false, it only handle MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN